# How to put a scrollbar in a tbody without breaking columns alignment

Tags: html, css

I am working on on a table right now and, I need to include a scrollbar on the y axis. My problem is that the scrollbar is breaking the alignment of my `<tbody>` and `<thead>` columns.

I have tried some stuff with calc() to correct the width of the `<td>` but, it wasn't a very successful attempt. I also tried making the `<th>` in thead larger than 100% in width when you add them so that it overflows over the scrollbar but, it did not work.

I don't really know what to do, if any of you guys see what could solve the problem, please tell me.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .main-container {
 background-color: #fbe1c8;
}

/**** Table design ****/

table.tableSection thead {
 float: left;
 width: 100%
}

table.tableSection tbody {
 float: left;
 width: 100%
}

table.tableSection tbody {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 150px 
}

.lbl {
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.libelleTableauTop {
 color: black;
 font-size: 8pt;
 font-family: Arial;
 border-color: #fbe1c8;
 margin-top: 0em;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 background-color: #ffa863;
}

.libelleTableauBot th {
 border-color: #fbe1c8;
 margin-top: 0em;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 background-color: #ffa863;
}

 /*** Parent row ***/

.parent {
 height: 5px;
 background-color: #fbe1c8;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.parent:hover {
 background-color:#4c94e8
}

.myCheckbox {
 width: 1%
}

.garantie {
 width: 29%
}

.valPrec {
 width: 14%
}

.cotisPrec {
 width: 14%
}

.indiceComp {
 width: 7%
}

.valTerme {
 width: 14%
}

.cotisTerme {
 width: 14%
}

.varIndice {
 width: 7%
}

th:hover {
 background-color:#4c94e8
}

table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid #fbe1c8;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableSection">

  <thead class="libelleTableauTop">
 <tr>
  <th colSpan="2">Garanties</th>
  <th colSpan="2">SITUATION PRECEDENTE</th>
  <th rowSpan="2">Mesure Terme<br><p>Indice compris</p></th>
  <th colSpan="2">SITUATION TERME</th>
  <th rowSpan="2">Variation Indice</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="libelleTableauBot">
  <th colSpan="2">Libellé Assiette</th>
  <th>Valeur Assiette</th>
  <th>Cotis. TTC Taux</th>
  <th>Valeur Assiette</th>
  <th>Cotis. TTC Taux</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th width="1%"></th>
  <th width="29%"></th>
  <th width="14%"></th>
  <th width="14%"></th>
  <th width="7%"></th>
  <th width="14%"></th>
  <th width="14%"></th>
  <th width="7%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  

  <tbody>
 <tr class="parent">
      <td class="myCheckbox"></td>
      <td class="lbl garantie">Responsabilité civile ava</td>
      <td class="valPrec"></td>
      <td class="garNbr cotisPrec">150,00</td>
      <td class="garNbr indiceComp">2,00 %</td>
      <td class="valTerme"></td>
      <td class="garNbr cotisTerme">150,00</td>
      <td class="varIndice"></td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: The best way is to use a javascript scroll. Why? It's because the native scrolls occupy width and are differents depending on the browser and operating system you are using. I recommend this easy-to-use scroll: https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Comment: is there a way not to use Js?

Comment: There is a way but you need to control the width of the scroll in Windows, Mac and Linux, and then for each operating system, control the width of the scroll in IE, Chrome, Firefox... And mobile? That scrolls don't have width, are floating scrolls. The best way is to use javascript, if you don't want to go to thumb after this.